# Programmatic way to change page size

Tags: google-app-maker

When I'm manipulating large data sets I don't want to have to page through them on the execution side, so I have the pageSize set to 0, but when i'm displaying it I want them to pages.

On the "datasources" page of the appmaker resources it says

> "For example, you can let the user control how many records are shown
>   by binding a slider widget's value property to the datasource pageSize
>   property."

How do I actually manipulate the pageSize property? this doesn't seem to work:

```
app.datasources.filesToCopy.properties.pageSize = 0;
app.datasources.filesToCopy.properties.pageSize = 20;
```

Anyone with any experience on this?

and this gives undefined:

Page length: undefined

```
console.log("Page length: "+app.datasources.filesToCopy.properties.pageSize);
```

Comment: Is this by chance a calculated datasource or just a regular SQL table datasource?

Comment: regular. I acutally found out how to do it but I am having trouble forcing it back.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is this:

```
app.datasources.filesToCopy.query.pageSize = 0;
```